# how does oplog collection work in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

in our application we use transaction. The primary and secondary node are on the same machine, there is no requirement for an high availability. Sometimes we have a transaction that runs over many mongodb update queries. The data that be updated can over 5 Gb and that leads to the problem that the oplog collection limit will reached. It ends with a Exception "MongoCommandException: Command update failed: Transaction has been aborted" Currently it is set to 10 Gb but i have to set it to over 100 Gb to make an successful transaction.
The application is used by one user at one time.

Can anybody explain me (or link to explaination :) ) why it is required to increase the limit so much? Or how can i avoid that the limit will reach? Why the collection cant grow dynamically for example?

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- Running a two node replica set is useless. You should remove the secondary so you end up with only a single node replica set
- OpLog is a capped collection (per node, stored in local database), so the size is changeable
- Running that big multi document transaction sounds fishy, you should really think about what exactly are you doing and do you really need a transaction? What kind of operations are you doing (inserts/updates/replace?)

Comment: i decide the big data should not be updated within the transaction, so the problem is solved. thank you for the hint.